# Selecting all lines/strings that fall between pattern in text file

Tags: python, regex, text-files

Given a text file that looks like this when loaded:

```
>rice1 1ALBRGHAER
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>peanuts2 2LAEKaq
SSSSSSSSSSS
>OIL3 3hkasUGSV
ppppppppppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppppppppppp
```

How can I extract all lines that fall between lines that contain '>' and the last lines where there is no ending '>' ?

For example, the result should look like this

```
result = ['NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN','SSSSSSSSSSS','pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp']
```

I'm realizing what I did won't work because its looking for text between each new line and '>'. Running this just gives me empty strings.

```
def findtext(inputtextfile, start, end):
    try:
       pattern=rf'{start}(.*?){end}'
       return re.findall(pattern, inputtextfile)
    except ValueError:
       return -1
result = findtext(inputtextfile,"\n", ">")
```

Comment: You can try [`>.*\s*([^>]+)`](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ygpsr3ys) and extract the contents from group 1 of each match and store it in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try splitting on rows that start with `>`, that way you get back a list of the data between and can join those after replacing the `\n`

```
s = """>rice1 1ALBRGHAER
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>peanuts2 2LAEKaq
SSSSSSSSSSS
>OIL3 3hkasUGSV
ppppppppppppppppppppp
ppppppppppppppppppppp"""

def findtext(inputtextfile, start, end):
    import re
    try:
        return [''.join(x.replace('\n','')) for x in list(filter(None,re.split(f'{start}.*{end}',s)))]
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Trying with your provided case

```
findtext(s, '>','\n')
```

Output

```
['NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN',
 'SSSSSSSSSSS',
 'pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp']
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using re.split  on the line that starts with `>` and then remove all the whitespace chars from the parts.

```
text = (">rice1 1ALBRGHAER\n"
     "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n"
     "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n"
     ">peanuts2 2LAEKaq\n"
     "SSSSSSSSSSS\n"
     ">OIL3 3hkasUGSV\n"
     "ppppppppppppppppppppp\n"
     "ppppppppppppppppppppp")


def findtext(inputtextfile):
    import re

    pattern = r"^>.*"
    
    try:
        return [re.sub(r"\s+", "", s) for s in re.split(pattern, inputtextfile, 0, re.M) if s]
    except ValueError:
        return -1


print(findtext(text))
```

Output (formatted a bit)

```
[
  'NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN',
  'SSSSSSSSSSS',
  'pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp'
]
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ocRe5i).